# SQL injection into insert statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been tasked with one insecure form, one secure form. For my insecure form, I have the PHP statement

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Name(Name) VALUES ('$firstname')";
```

Here the user input is obviously taken directly from the from and saved as `$firstname`. Now, I am having trouble actually injecting SQL into this form. Could someone point me in the right direction? I've tried dropping the table but I either get a SQL error or the injection actually is inserted.

EDIT: This is different from the question that is apparently a duplicate, as I know HOW to make it secure, what I'm trying to do is inject my already insecure code. The example in the duplicate question did not work for me and gave a syntax error.

Comment: Could you include examples of injections you've tried?

Comment: I have tried the "duplicate" example which simply gives me a SQL error.

`example'); DROP TABLE Name;--` 

gives the error

`Could not get data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TABLE Name;--')' at line 1`

Comment: In most cases you can't run multiple queries like this, unless the script is using specific functions to allow that behaviour. But you can run a query inside the other, usually `SELECT`, like this: `'), (SELECT password FROM mysql.user WHERE name = 'root'), ('` I'm not sure if you have to do something else for this to work though, but thats pretty much the way.